# Stop watching google push notifications

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am using the Google Reports API to watch for changes to resources, such as a user's Google Calendar activity events. To achieve this, a channel (or watchpoint) was created by following the steps here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/watch

Now, I would like to stop watching a resource before the channel expires. I sent a POST request along with a access token in the header and the body contains the channel id and the resource id (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/channels/stop). However I keep getting a 404 Not Found. Am I doing something wrong here?

All other requests using the same access token are working fine.

My request/response looks like this:

```
POST /admin/reports/v1/channels/stop HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 97
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.rAExOpnO_gatfyJvKWEVt8OsQ-LyaCyN3UUFjYzm0-3ExEBZ9an7WWfdDLqJspChQaiiIQ
{
  "id": "5cfc250b-2faf-4f86-91b3-398326c6b4fb",
  "resourceId": "A_HZ7mQy0Zpd6-TkQjr3aQlWd94"
}


HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-length: 9
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin,X-Origin
Server: GSE
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 17:10:40 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Not Found
```

Comment: Do you see the same 404 error on the OAuth Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)? Could you edit and include you request/response (sanitize as necessary)?

Comment: Yes, same 404 error. I've also noticed that the request URI for the stop operation on OAuth Playground is different than what's listed in the developer documentation. I've tried both ones...

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug if you're seeing the same issue on the OAuth Playground. If you're a Google Apps admin, you can log a case with Google to have them check/confirm this. You can also file an issue here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the request URL specified in the documentation is wrong.
The correct one is 
    https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports_v1/channels/stop

Issue reported here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3914