# Google Admin SDK Channel Stop endpoint is broken in client libraries

Tags: google-admin-sdk

There appears to be something wrong with the Google Admin SDK Channel Stop endpoint affecting all the language libraries. At least Node, Ruby and PHP.

I'm having the issue with "directory"…

- It should be: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/channels/stop (404)
- This works: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory_v1/channels/stop
- This is generated: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1//admin/directory_v1/channels/stop (404)

Someone else if having the problem with "reports"…
[Stop watching google push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327874/stop-watching-google-push-notifications)

Ruby library issue…
https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/251

Node client: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/1c0407e56e12a05ec8fa7679df19bdd2436969f5/apis/admin/directory_v1.js

Ruby client: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/41d9d66e8190c8ced331fcc5e156c5123941d713/generated/google/apis/admin_directory_v1/service.rb

PHP client: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/da350e19472f5711703a68a77c6df8d1f5ed4fd4/src/Google/Service/Directory.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this appears to be a bug in our API serving system that only affects the Admin SDK Directory and Reports APIs. I'm working with the team to find a resolution.