# Trying to stop Google Directory API push notifications with a client returns 404

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client, google-directory-api

Using the documentation at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push#creating-notification-channels I subscribed to a notification using something like:

```py
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
watch_data = {
    'id': str(uuid.uuid1()),
    'type': 'web_hook',
    'address': 'https://example.appspot.com/push/user',
    'payload': True,
}
subscription = service.users().watch(domain=domain, event='update', body=watch_data).execute()
# 'subscription' is stored
```

I got a proper reply and everything seem fine to that point.

Until I try to stop the notification with the following code:

```py
# 'subscription' is retrieved from the storage
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
stop_data = {
    'id': subscription.id,
    'resourceId': subscription.resource_id
}
request = service.channels().stop(body=stop_data)
request.execute()
```

This raises an 'HttpError' 404 exception:

```
Response: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/admin/directory_v1/channels/stop? returned "Not Found">
```

Interestingly, using the same parameters (known good 'id' and 'resourceId' from the same user), the API explorer gadget at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/channels/stop fails in the same way.

I've also been unable to find this endpoint in the full blown API explorer.

I believe that the discovery somewhat misbehaves.

The URI built by the client is:  'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/admin/directory_v1/channels/stop'
whereas the documentation states it should be:
'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/channels/stop'.

Could this be a bug in the API?

I'll try to make a "manual" authenticated request ASAP to check this hypothesis.

**Edit 2016-11-09:**

Tried a manual request using the following code:

```py
# 'subscription' is retrieved from the storage
stop_data = {
    'id': subscription.id,
    'resourceId': subscription.resource_id
}
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/channels/stop'
method = 'POST'
response, content = http.request(url, method, body=json.dumps(stop_data),
                                 headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

I still get a 404 as a result. So I guess that the problem is not the endpoint URI.

If someone from Google reads this, can you please look into it?

It's not super critical but I'd like to not have dangling notification subscriptions.

**Edit 2 2016-11-09:**

Thanks to @Mr.Rebot for pointing out the reports API bug report.
Upon closer inspection, the problem here is exactly the same.
Using the manual request code above but adjusting the URI with an underscore, I'm finally able to make a successful request (returns 204).

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory_v1/channels/stop'
```

So there's definitely a bug somewhere and the following documentation pages have the wrong endpoint URI:

- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push#stopping-notifications
- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/channels/stop

Also found this related post: [Google Admin SDK Channel Stop endpoint is broken in client libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735463/google-admin-sdk-channel-stop-endpoint-is-broken-in-client-libraries)

Comment: I agree sounds like a bug.  love to hear what you find in the manual call.

Comment: You might want to check this [methods show incorrect URL in documentation](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3914) on how they debug this kind of issue in Admin SDK. Here is the related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31839251/5995040) where it was reported. I would agree with @DaImTo, it would be great if you will be able to provide the result of the manual call.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been sick the last few days. I edited the post to add the manual request. Still getting a 404.

Answer (score 0):

To those that wonders in the Google Docs hell for the past two years, and counting.

The wrong/right URL is:

`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports_v1/channels/stop`

And the Scope to use this URL is:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly`

I hope this helps someone :)